# How to continue the maven release:perfom from the failed point

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-release-plugin

Can u please any one suggest how to continue the maven release:perform from the failed point.

Since the some of the jars got uploaded in the nexus. We need to continue the build fromt he failed point. If we start from the first, we will get 400 error.

So please suggest how to continue the release:perfrom from the failed point?

Thanks in advance.

Regarsds,
Karthik

Answer (score 1):

If you have already artifacts in Nexus you need to manually delete those artifacts and afterwards restart with:

```
mvn release:perform
```

And furthermore i would really analyze why the build has failed and what the root cause was.